# Why if and else both are true in option taq of a html select taq

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Its realy strange..what is wrong with this one..??
   I want to selected one option in my select drop down by default.so if a value is poseted my if condition got true then why the else is also executing.Your Help Will be really appreciated.

```
<select name="location" id="location" class="selector_holder_select">

<?php foreach($location as $loc){ ?>

<option value="<?php echo $loc['deal_location_id']; ?>"

<?php if($loc['deal_location_id']==$_POST['location']){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }

else { 

if(strcasecmp($loc['location'], $city['cityName']) == 0) { echo 
'selected="selected"';     }

 } ?>><?php echo $loc['location']; ?></option>

 <?php } //End of Foreach ?> 

 </select>
```

Comment: Use a codeblock for you code..

Comment: Err... there is no if/else in your code. Please post the relevant parts of your code and add a few lines before and after.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: What a disaster. Please use `echo` to do HTML inside your PHP, instead of the other way round. Or use a decent template system.

Comment: What is it doing and what should it do? This code doesn't look wrong functionally.

Comment: well, i can't understand why after each loop he added index to string $loc and after implementing foreach loop on $location at the same time in the if statment he is using `if($loc['deal_location_id']==$_POST['location'])` well, thats confusing!

Comment: hi, yes you are absolutely right..in next iteration else is true. but i could not understand how to solve it. Basically my requirement is I have a registration form.where i am printing location from database. if a user goes to registration form his location should be autoselected if that is present in db. but if user select any other location instead of his default location and he enter wrong captcha and back to register form with error then form should show his selected location instead of his current city location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Above not solve my issue.However this one worked.But can any body make it          
  shorter  and cleanup so it looks more professional.


   <select name="location" id="location" class="selector_holder_select">
   <?php foreach($location as   $loc){  ?>                  
    <option value="<?php echo $loc['deal_location_id']; ?>"
    <?php               
   if($loc['deal_location_id']==$_POST['location'])
   {
    echo 'selected="selected"'; 
   } 
   else {     
        if(strcasecmp($loc['location'], $city['cityName']) == 0 and !isset($_POST['location']))
        { echo 'selected="selected"'; } 
   } ?>>
<?php echo $loc['location']; ?></option>

 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with this code is that you mix HTML and PHP quite heavily. This makes is very hard to read. I recommend using HEREDOC or something similar to create all the HTML parts instead of switching PHP on and off that often.

I guess what happens is that once in the foreach loop the first if-condition is met and once (in a different iteration step) the elseif is met. That way two elements get selected.

The problem is, that you cannot solve this problem in a single foreach. You first have to check whether the if-case will be true at some point. If so you can set the respective field selected. If not you can search for the else-if and handle that.

Comment: hi,
yes you are absolutely right..in next iteration else is true.
but i could not understand how to solve it.
Basically my requirement is
I have a registration form.where i am printing location from database.
if a user goes to registration form his location should be autoselected if that is present in db.
but if user select any other location instead of his default location and he enter wrong captcha and back to register form with error then form should show his selected location instead of his current city location.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select name="location" id="location" class="selector_holder_select">
<?php foreach($location as $loc){
    echo('<option value="'.$loc['deal_location_id'].'"')
    if($loc['deal_location_id'] == $_POST['location'] || strcasecmp($loc['location'], $city['cityName']) == 0)
        echo(' selected="selected"');
    echo(">".$loc['location']."</option>");
?>
</select>
```

However I recommend you to follow a tutorial about the basics of PHP, for example [this from W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp). It looks like you've got no PHP-experience whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="location" id="location" class="selector_holder_select">
    <?php 
    foreach($location as $loc) {
            echo "<option value=$loc['deal_location_id']>";

            if($loc['deal_location_id']==$_POST['location']) { 
                echo 'selected="selected"'; 
            } else { 
                if(strcasecmp($loc['location'], $city['cityName']) == 0) { 
                    echo 'selected="selected"';     
                }
            }

            echo "$loc['location']</option>";
  }
</select>
```